# ObservableCollection of objects each containing an ObservableCollection not updating, even if the same object is in more OC's

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I hope the title is understandable, but anyhow I will try to describe the problem as best i can.
I have an ObservableCollection GroupList which contains objects of the type Group. The class Group is very simple:

```
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>();
    }

    public Group(string name)
    {
        Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>();
        GroupName = name;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

The GroupList is the ItemsSource of a ComboBox I have in my View, determining which ObservableCollection of Members to show in a ListBox. The properties of the SelectedItem in the ListBox is then bound to some TextBoxes to show Name, Age etc for each Member.

My problem is that I have a Group with Name="All members" and other groups where the Members are also present. Group A contains Member A+B and Group B contains Member B+C, but Group All members contains A+B+C. However, if I change the properties of say Member A in Group A, it is not reflected in Group All members. I have spent days trying to figure out what is wrong, since it works like a charm if I test it in a new project (written off memory):

```
ObservableCollection<Member> MembersA = new ObservableCollection<Member>;
ObservableCollection<Member> MembersA = new ObservableCollection<Member>;
Member newMember = new Member("TestMember",1986);
MembersA.Add(newMember);
MembersB.Add(newMember);
MembersA.First().Name="TestMemberChanged";
```

This updates the member in both OC's but not in my project and i can't figure out what is wrong. Do I need to implement an interface like INotifyPropertyChanged for Member and Group as well? (It is already implemented for GroupList in the VM). Or do I need to manually update all OC's in the events OnPropertyChanged or CollectionChanged?

```
private ObservableCollection<Group> _groupList;
    public ObservableCollection<Group> GroupList
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupList;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupList = value;
            Notify("GroupList");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I realise that my architechture might be inefficient, so any suggestions how to improve it, are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you said already the answer: you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged also for the Member class and raise that event when a property of Member like 'Name' has changed it's value. This is because an ObservableCollection notifies the user interface just when items are added/removed/reordered from the list but not when a property value of one item in the list has changed.

Comment: That was fast! Thank you very much, it works like a charm! (I just wonder why it didn't work earlier, but something must have changed since i tried with INotifyPropertyChanged last time).